# Order by one-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, doctrine, foreign-keys, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables:

```
Message:
    id:         INT
    created_at: DATETIME

Comment:
    id:         INT
    message_id: INT
    created_at: DATETIME
```

One `Message` has many `Comments`.

I want to get all `Messages` ordered by the most recent activity:

- If `Message` has `Comments`, then the most recent `Comment`'s `created_at` is used as the `Message` activity indicator
- If `Message` doesn't have `Comments`, it's `created_at` value is the activity indicator

So basically, I want to sort it like a classic e-mail or private messaging system.

Maybe I can `INNER JOIN` the Comments, but I don't think it's necessary to get all the Comments just for the sort.

Also, I thought about creating a column in `Message` to save the last activity date and update it whenever a `Comment` is created, but I'd like to see if you have better solutions..

I'm using Doctrine, so if you have a Doctrine-based solution I'd rather that,

Thanks!

Comment: Which version? 1.2 or 2.0 (or 2.1, but I doubt it matters for this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do in MySQL is something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Messages AS m
ORDER BY GREATEST(
   m.created_at, 
   (SELECT MAX( c.created_at ) FROM Comment AS c WHERE c.message_id = m.id )
) DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `GREATEST()`. Edited.

Comment: the only problem is that if there are no Comments, the SELECT will return null and therefor, GREATEST will return null as well, pushing all the non-commented messages down the list..

Comment: Try this:

`SELECT *
FROM Messages AS m
ORDER BY GREATEST(
   m.created_at, 
   IFNULL((SELECT MAX( c.created_at ) FROM Comment AS c WHERE c.message_id = m.id ),'0000-00-00')
) DESC`

This would be assuming `Messages.created_at` always has a value, which I assume it has.

Comment: how about this? `ORDER BY IFNULL(
  (SELECT MAX(c.created_at) FROM Comment c
   WHERE c.message_id = m.id), m.created_at
) DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select m.message_id, c.created_at, m.created_at 
from message m
left join (
    select message_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at
    from comment
    group by message_id
) c on m.id = c.message_id
order by 
    ( case when c.created_at >= m.created_at then c.created_at
          else m.created_at
     end ) desc
```

The subquery will get most current comment date for each message, then message table will outer join the subquery because some message might not have any comments at all. Then order by greater value of comment created date and message created date.

You might need to change the case syntax for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If your comment table's id is an auto-incrment you can simply order by id desc and it will return the results in chronological order as long as you aren't doing deletes on the comment table which has a tendency to make inserts show up out of chronological order.  Otherwise, you need to do something like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.created_at 
FROM Message a, Comment b 
WHERE b.created_at > a.created_at 
ORDER BY b.created_at DESC
```

Comment: but this will only select the records where b.created_at > a.created_at, what if there is no b (Comment) to the Message?

Comment: You are correct.  I thought you were only interested in the order by syntax.  Still I think you could do this in two steps, a subquery, or using ifs. Looks like some of the other answers are more descriptive and complete.